# Как запустить Service один раз после установки приложения

Tags: android, android-service

Ребята, у меня есть Service,который проверяет постоянно кое-какую задачу.

Я его запускаю в MainActivity.

Но каждый раз,когда я выхожу из приложения и захожу обратно,у меня заново запускается Service.

Как мне запустить его один раз после установки,чтобы потом он всегда работал и выполнял свою задачу в фоне?

MainActivity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
```

Comment: По-моему вы решаете проблему, которой нет. Сервис запускается все равно только один раз, если он работает, `startService()` просто вызовет у него `onStartCommand()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы его запускаете каждый раз когда запускается `Activity`. Попробуйте проверять его работу и не запускать если она уже запущена.

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

в `onCreate`

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

if(!isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class)){
     startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
}
```

Comment: Нужно создать класс private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) в MainActivity и в метод OnCreate добавить выше перичисленный код?

Comment: Работает ШИКАРНО!